# How to fix "503 Service Unavailable" error on Postman for server hosted on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, postman

If I host this server locally, it works perfectly on Postman (and stores the data on MongoDB), however, once hosted on Heroku, it gives me a 503 error. Does anyone have any ideas about what to do?

[Local Host Working #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekcUz.png)

[Local Host Working #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92cz.png)

[Local Host Working #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dOZF.png)

[503 Error Occurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eo6Q.png)

I've heard from other's that it might be a CORS error. Not sure about the relation between CORS and Postman however. Here's my package.json, just in case:

```
{
  "name": "login_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

And, here's my server.js:

```
    //mongodb
    require('./config/db');
    
    const app = require('express')();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    // cors accesss to enable application on different hosts to send request
    const cors = require("cors");
    app.use(cors());
    
    const UserRouter = require('./api/User');
    
    // For accepting post form data
    const bodyParser = require('express').json;
    app.use(bodyParser());
    
    app.use('/user', UserRouter);
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
    })
```

Thanks so much in advance. Cheers.

Comment: A 503 response isn't related to CORS. I'm removing that tag from your question.

Comment: Where you able to see the logs in the `heroku cli` for that app, is everything looks ok on the server side?

Comment: if you have deployed the application to heroku using the cli, you can login using cli and use `heroku logs --app=my-app`  to trace the logs refer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs

Comment: myself i was building some personal app, you can check this server.js i used but for angular ui. https://github.com/thirumurthis/stock-angular-ui/blob/main/server.js

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by going to MongoDB (where this was stored), and set "network access" IP to 0.0.0.0/0.